# How to reach Dongzhimen Metro station from Beijing Capital Airport?

Tags: public-transport, china, beijing, pek

As stated in the title, what is the easiest way to reach to Dongzhimen Metro station from Beijing Capital Airport (PEK)?

Answer (score 7):

Take the Beijing Subway Airport Express Line (北京地铁机场线). It goes right from Dongzhimen to PEK with only one stop in between.

There are two stations at PEK, one in Terminal 2 and one in Terminal 3. The Airport Express costs ￥25 per trip, for which you could either use a Beijing public transportation card or buy a single-trip ticket at a vending machine, located in the Dongzhimen station.

Comment: This is correct. It was 25 RMB when I took it this January.